# Яндекс.Справочник , объединить филиалы в сеть

Tags: seo

Есть организация ее филиалы нужно объединить в Яндекс.Справочнике в сеть, сейчас информация в Яндексю.Справочнике есть только от 2 филиалах.
Что нужно что бы объединить их?

Answer (score 1):

Подайте заявку на объединение филиалов в сеть через форму

https://yandex.ru/sprav/support/branches/several-branches.html#add__add-form

В заявке укажите:

- название сети организаций;
- единый сайт сети;
- рубрику Справочника или вид деятельности сети;
- общий телефон сети;
- названия и телефоны всех филиалов сети, которые есть в Справочнике.

Когда данные будут добавлены, на указанный адрес будет отправлено уведомление. Обычно на добавление новой сети и привязку филиалов уходит около двух суток.

В хелпе вроде [все описано](https://yandex.ru/sprav/support/branches/several-branches.html). 
И я не уверен, что 2 филиалов достаточно для сети. Может быть нижняя планка по количеству филиалов.

Answer (score 1):

Условия объединения в сеть

Два и более филиалов можно объединить в единую сеть. При этом они должны обладать следующими общими свойствами:

- иметь одинаковое название (без учета организационно-правовой формы и вида деятельности);
- относиться к одному виду деятельности (рубрике);
- иметь общий сайт или общий номер телефона.